# Password hash in apex oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

i'm trying to hash or encrypt the password provided by the user in my apex oracle before store it in the DB table How can i do it ? i tried using `DBMS_CRYPTO` but it always generate an error saying

```
identifier 'DBMS_CRYPTO' must be declared
```

i have tried to grant execute privilege to PUBLIC and Administrator but no luck there

Comment: If you're using a common stored procedure like DBMS_CRYPTO in your own PL/SQL code, your database user must be granted the `execute` privilege on it explicitly - it cannot be granted through a role or through `public`.